# I don't know some words in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Of course, Britain is now in unknown, volatile territory. Brexit strains, combined with a working majority of just 16, could force her to seek a personal mandate from voters at an early election, or even bring down her premiership.

What is personal mandate? is mandate authority?so does that mean she has an authority to hold a snap election?

http://www.theworldin.com/article/12586/wait-fall

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is worded like a proofreading question. Proofreading is off-topic on ELL, and that would make this question eligible for closure. Please [limit your question to a specific area of concern](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/260/), or consider [Alternative websites for proofreading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/).

Comment: @M.A.R. why would this look like proofreading?

Comment: You drastically changed the question, in a way that my comment would no longer apply. It's all evident from the revisions to your question. Now, to your updated version, what do you think "personal mandate" is supposed to mean? Have you checked a dictionary for what "mandate" means? If so, what about the definition seemed vague to you? Please [edit] your question to clarify, because it's hard to know why you're asking this question.

Comment: I've  clarified it

Comment: have you looked up strain in a dictionary? I see no reference to demand in this one: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain  ... and have you looked up mandate in the dictionary, as M.A.R suggested? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mandate

Comment: @JavaLatte yes that's why I'm asking the question in the first place.

Comment: Can you provide a reference that shows that strain means demand?

Comment: @JavaLatte No. Now I think it is anxiety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brexit is a political hot potato: it is [a force or influence that stretches, pulls, or puts pressure on something, sometimes causing damage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain). Many are in favour of Brexit, but few are brave or foolish enough to proceed with it.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mandate) defines a **mandate** as

> the authority given to an elected group of people, such as a government, to perform an action or govern a country

As Prime Minister, Teresa May already has the authority to hold a snap election, as a PM can call an election at any time. What she is seeking is a personal mandate- an authority given to one person (Teresa May)- to go ahead with the changes required for Brexit in the face of stiff opposition.

Comment: So could it also contain more seats for pro Brexit memebers of parliament?

Comment: The voters do not vote for the Prime Minister: they just vote for a Member of Parliament to represent them. If more pro-Brexit MPs are elected, Teresa May would regard that as a personal mandate to proceed.